# .override file isn't working

Tags: services, upstart, init

I have a file `/etc/init/boinc-client.override` with the single line `manual` that I use to prevent the BOINC client from starting up. (I don't want it hogging CPU time away from Folding@Home, for now anyway.)

But, after restarting, I noticed that BOINC had started itself up again.

I am sure that, I have upstart installed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boinc-client` doesn't use Upstart but SysV Init to start at boot time.

Use

```
sudo update-rc.d boinc-client disable
```

to disable automatic starting up. If you want to enable it again use

```
 sudo update-rc.d boinc-client enable
```

Comment: Super ... I'd upvote you if I could but this is my first question here. Sorry...